# How to format a log record inside ```emit``` function instead of creating a formatter object?

Tags: python, python-logging

I wrote a custom logging handler to send a log record to a http point.

```
class CustomHttpHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, url: str):
        # url is the endpoint to send log
        self.url = url
        self.session = requests.Session()
  

    def emit(self, record):
        self.session.post(self.url, data=record)
```

```
import logging
from handler import CustomHttpHandler


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

formatter = logging.Formatter(json.dumps({
    'time': '%(asctime)s',
    message': '%(message)s'
}))

handler = CustomHandler("http://myurl")

logger.addHandler(chandler)
logger.setFormatter(formatter)
```

Is there any way that I can format a log record inside `emit` function instead of creating formatter object and pass it with `setFormatter` function?

Comment: Why not using [`HTTPHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem using setFormatter, you just need to use it in your `emit` function like so

```
def emit(self, record):  
    print(self.format(record))
```

Also note that you can apply your formater only to this specific handler if you want:

```
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```